# VBA - I have blank rows between every line to space out content. How can I maintain blank rows for spacing when I use an autofilter macro?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to autofilter by a specific criteria (Specific Column = "Yes"). Prior to autofilter, every other row is a blank space which is used to space out the data.

As you can imagine, when I autofilter, the blank spaces are filtered out and I lose the spacing. I tried adding blank spaces to the criteria for filtering but then there is major gaps between the data (sometimes there can be 5 spaces consecutively.

How can I filter for the criteria "Yes" and make sure there's only one blank space in between each result?

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=40
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=40, Criteria1:= _
    "Yes"
```

Comment: Just increase the rows' height instead of adding empty rows. If you want, you can also adjust the vertical alignment to `center` the content. Alternatively, you can make the filter criteria to be `(blank)` or `Yes`.

Comment: The short answer is, You can't.  The autofilter is not designed that way.  There are work arounds. @Ralph stated one, the other is to copy the data to another page and then loop through backwards and add empty lines.

Comment: Scott could you please elaborate on how I do this?

Answer (score 1):

The solution you should go with: increasing row height.

```
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range
    .AutoFilter Field:=40
    .AutoFilter Field:=40, Criteria1:="Yes"
    .EntireRow.RowHeight = 20 ' Your value here
End With
```

The solution for keeping blank rows: copying data to another sheet, adding blank rows

```
' Create the FilteredData worksheet in your workbook first
Dim FilteredSheet as Worksheet
Set FilteredSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FilteredData")
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range
    .AutoFilter Field:=40
    .AutoFilter Field:=40, Criteria1:="Yes"
     ' copy data, must be paste special values or will also copy hidden filtered data
    .Copy 
    TempSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    ' Clear clipboard
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ' Loop over, insert rows
    Dim rw As Long
    For rw = FilteredSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count To 2 Step -1
        FilteredSheet.Cells(rw,1).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Next rw
End With
```

Note that for the second option, you'll also have to clear all the previously filtered data first, and it will be *really* slow by comparison to just changing the row height.

Answer (score -1):

You could write an mimic autofilter function for yourself, that takes a range to search and a value to search for as arguments, then it loops through the range: if it does not find the value in a cell or the cell above that, it hides the row.

I mean something like this:

```
' cl is the number of column, vl is the string to search for
Sub MimicFilter(cl As Integer, vl As String) 

    Dim i As Long
    i = 2 'If there is a header

    Do Until i = Cells(Rows.Count, cl).End(xlUp).Row

        Rows(i).Select
        If Cells(i, cl).value = vl Then
            Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = False 'in case it was hidden before
        ElseIf Cells(i - 1, cl).value = vl Then
            Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = False 'in case it was hidden before
        Else
            Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If

        i = i + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: The person who downvoted me, would you please tell me why?

Comment: I'm not the downvoter here and I don't see anything particularly objectionable about this answer, but a word of advice: *don't ever use `Integer` type for a row iterator*. The number of rows in Excel 2003 greatly exceeds the maximum allowable integer, and in Excel 2007+ it's an order of magnitude more.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I haven't run into that yet, but good advice. I edited it.

Comment: FYI: the limit of integer data type is 32,767 (there are 65,536 rows in Excel 2003, and over 1MM in Excel 2007+)